# Debugging a C# file from Visual Studio Extension

Tags: c#, debugging

I have my own Visual Studio Extension in which I am building a class Library project and get the DLL out of it. I will be loading the DLL and call the methods inside the DLL from my Visual Studio Extension window. Is there a way to enable the debugging option, so that when it executes the method inside that DLL, it breaks at a breakpoint in the cs file.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: When you add a 2nd project you should use the menu Add Reference and then browse to the dll in the debug folder of 2nd project.  There is a pdb file which contains the debug data as well as the location of the source files.

Comment: Thanks jdweng for the response. In my Extension window of Visual Studio, I am accessing the DLL file. I have only one project in my Solution explorer and it has a Class Library project (DLL file which I am accessing from my Extension). So I need to debug this dll from my Extension. Already I have pdb file in parallel to my DLL and symbols are loaded for the DLL which I can see it in Modules Window.

Comment: What happens if you put a break point at the DLL in main project.  Then step into using F11?  I usually find I have to step into project and then add additional break points in 2nd project.  Once one break point is in the 2nd project it makes it easy to debug.

Comment: My main project is Visual Studio Extension type of project, I have installed that extension in Visual Studio and accessing the DLL from my Extension Window (similar to Solution Explorer, Properties window, etc..). So I will not be having the Source Code of my Main Project.

Comment: The either create a test project or create a wrapper between the main project and dll that you use for debugging.  Worse case create a log file in 2nd project and write debug data to log file.  I recently had a lot of code to debug on a machine that didn't have VS installed and did all my debugging through a log file.

Comment: thanks again @jdweng for your response. Logfile might not work in our case. I will look into the options of having a wrapper project between my main project and dll. By any chance do you have any reference links or sample code for wrapper project case?

Comment: A wrapper is simply a module that takes input from parameter list and then call another module with parameters modified.  Many Net library methods are wrappers that simply call Windows Dlls.  Since the Windows dlls are not managed the Net library has to take the parameters and put into unmanaged memory before calling.